# Self Levelling and Liquid DPM over damp on ground floor quarry tiles - disaster

Tags: water-damage, carpet, self-leveling-concrete, damp-proof-course, damp

I have a question about rising damp on quarry tiles ground floor in old building.

I removed the old carpet and realised there was damp patches on the tiled floor below, im believe there is no dpm membrane and quarry tiles were laid over lime morter bed, my contractors PVA'ed self levelled over the floor to try and stop it but the self levelling got blown up and was cracked in certain spots, so i chipped off all the blown self levelling and painted over with liquid DPM, but now that started to bubble and crack because it was brushed over the self levelling that wasnt cracked and the moisture got trapped under the self levelling and that cracked.

My question is what is my best option other than digging it all up and laying a dpm sheet, should I chip off all the broken spots and rip all the parts where its bubbled and cracked and get it back to the quarry tiles and and let the moisture breathe through the quarry tiles and just lay underlay and carpet over it and hope there is no damp patches and it just breathes througg and evaporates or should i chip off all the old self levelling and then paint over the area with liquid DPM again, but if i paint over, will the moisture just travel to another area?

Any advice would be helpful.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: "...my contractors PVA'ed self levelled over the floor to try and stop it but the self levelling got blown up ..."   What does that mean?   What is your location and what year was your house built?

Comment: The builders decided to pva over the quarry floor and then put self levelling concrete over it, but that didnt fix the issue, it cracked n got blown. Im in the UK, west midlands

Comment: Please explain  What is PVA ?

Comment: Its a polymer based adhesive

Comment: A glue in other words...

Comment: PVA is a common name for wood glue. But I  don't know what DPM is.

Comment: *damp proof membrane* ... An apt title for what you actually said, +1. How refreshing. Except .... yeah. You can borrow my ten foot pole if you want?